# Splat operator in Ruby (a quicksort example)

Tags: ruby

Hello I'm studying some Ruby code. Implement Quicksort in Ruby:

```
1 def qsort(lst)
2   return [] if lst.empty?
3   x, *xs = *lst
4   less, more = xs.partition{|y| y < x}
5   qsort(less) + [x] + qsort(more)
6 end
```

Given:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

x, *xs = *lst
```

I do not know if I understand what line 3 is doing correctly:

From my observation and experiment, this will assign `1` from `lst` to `x`, and the rest of `lst` to `xs`.

Also I found these two are doing the same thing:

```
x, *xs = *lst
```

is equivalent to

```
x, *xs = lst
```

My question is, what's the name of this nice feature (I will edit the title afterwards to adapt)? Then I could study more about this Ruby feature myself. Sorry if it's a duplicate problem, because I don't know the keyword to search on this problem.

Comment: that qsort function is some beautiful ruby code. the reason why `x, *xs = lst` is equivalent to `x, *xs = *lst` is because `x, y = [1, 2]` is equivalent to `x, y = 1, 2` which actually is `x, y = *[1, 2]`. apparently, in the first case there is an implicit splat when you have an array on the right site and more than one variable on the left site you are assigning to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name of this feature is called **splat** operator in Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

> The splat operator in Ruby, Groovy and Perl allows you to switch between parameters and arrays:it splits a list in a series of parameters,or collects a series of parameters to fill an array.

From [4 Lines of Code](http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/01/16/the-splat-operator-in-ruby/).

Answer (score 1):

This statement

```
x, *xs = *lst
```

doesn't make much sense to me, but these do:

```
x, *xs = [1, 2, 3] # x -> 1, xs -> [2, 3]
x = 1, *[2, 3, 4] # x -> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

this usage IMO has nothing to do with parameters, but as others said splat can be (and usually is) used with parameters:

```
def foo(a, b, c)
end

foo(*[1,2,3]) # a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3
```