# Check array's elements are of the same size

Tags: ruby, arrays

is there a best and efficient way to check if array's elements are of the same size?

```
[[1,2], [3,4], [5]] => false

[[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]] => true
```

What I've got:

```
def element_of_same_size?(arr)
  arr.map(&:size).uniq.size == 1
end
```

Another solution:

```
def element_of_same_size?(arr)
  arr[1..-1].each do |e|
    if e.size != arr.first.size
      return false
    else
      next
    end
  end
  return true
end
```

This one will return false immediately when it finds a element is not the same size as the first one.

Is there a best way to do this? (Of course...)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What about using the [`Enumerable#all?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F) method?

```
def element_of_same_size?(arr)
  arr.all? { |a| a.size == arr.first.size }
end

element_of_same_size?([[1,2], [3,4], [5]])
# => false

element_of_same_size?([[1,2], [3,4], [5, 6]])
# => true
```

Comment: perfect answer for this question.

Answer (score 3):

To deliver one more one-liner:

You can use [`chunk`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk) and [`one?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-one-3F)

```
[[1,2], [3,4], [7,8], [5,6]].chunk(&:size).one?
```

Comment: `[[1,2], [3,4], [7,8], [5,6,9]].partition(&:size).last.empty?` is also `true`

Comment: @juanitofatas right, removed it, thanks! chunk and one is more beautiful anyway

Comment: the chunk method is reallly slow, more than 1 second to evaluate this 100,000 times (see my answer)

Comment: @Aaron_H Ah ok, I see now, 100'000 times. It's actually the `Enumerator#one?` that's a bit costly, yes. But hey, it's a oneliner, and 2x-4x is not an extreme performance overhead.

Answer (score 2):

I like toro2k's answer.  I just wanted to add the possibility of adding the method to the array class itself and warn you that elements which are not arrays but respond to the **size** method could still return true.
(edit: false if empty array)

```
class Array
  def same_element_size?
    return false if self.empty?
    sz = self.first.size
    self.all? {|k| k.size==sz}
  end
end

ar  = [[1,2], [3,4], [5]]
ar2 = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
ar3 = [[1,2], 'hi', [4,5]]

[[], ar, ar2, ar3].each {|array|
  puts "%30s --> %s" % [array.inspect, array.same_element_size?]
}

#                            [] --> false
#         [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5]] --> false
#      [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]] --> true
#        [[1, 2], "hi", [4, 5]] --> true
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for the fun of it, if extending `Array` is your choice, you can go for something more flexible, like implementing a `same?` method:

```
class Array
  def same? &block
    if block_given?
      f = block.call(first)
      all? {|a| block.call(a) == f}
    else
      all? {|a| a == first }
    end
  end
end
```

This allows:

```
[[1,2], [5,6], [8,9]].same?(&:size)
```

or

```
[[1,2], [7,8], [5,6], [8,9]].same?(&:max)
```

or just (by default will compare with `==`)

```
[[1,2], [7,8], [5,6], [8,9]].same?
```

Answer (score 0):

Some benchmarks:

```
                                  user     system      total        real
  standalone all                0.234000   0.000000   0.234000 (  0.246025)
  class method all              0.234000   0.000000   0.234000 (  0.235024)
  class method transpose        0.920000   0.000000   0.920000 (  0.940094)
  chunk and one?                1.591000   0.000000   1.591000 (  1.610161)
```

My money is on the class method using Enumerable#all? by toko2k

Answer (score 0):

If dealing with an array of non nested arrays, you could test to ensure the matrix is square. It throws recursive arrays out the window but is kind of concise.

```
require 'matrix'

a1 = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
a2 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
a3 = [[1,2],3,4,[5,6]]

Matrix[a1].square? == true
Matrix[a2].square? == true
Matrix[a3].square? == false
```